# Combine 2 Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have 2 datatable

First datatable has only column name

Ex: A   B

Second Datatable has column name with values

```
 A  B  C  D                                                                         
 1  2  3  4                                                                           
 2  3  4  5
```

Now how can i get the values from second datatable to first datatable with columns matching

End result of  First Datatable should be like

```
A  B                                                                               
1  2
```

I tried merge but datatype mismatch occurs

Comment: If the first one has no data, why not create it from the second with a SELECT statement?

Comment: @Plutonix my requirement  is  i need to get values from second datatable to first datatable ..

Comment: That may be hard to do if they are not the same column datatypes (as per the error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DefaultView.ToTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allows you to specify which columns you want in the new Table

In this example I use the variable *tableWithData* to represent the datatable with the value you want to extract and the variable *tableWithoutData* to represent the table with only the column names. The variable *newTable* is another datatable that receives the result of the ToTable method, but you could also use *tableWithoutData* as the destination of the call.

```
Dim newTable = tableWithData.DefaultView.ToTable(False, tableWithoutData.Columns _
      .Cast(Of DataColumn)() _
      .Select(Function(x) x.ColumnName) _
      .ToArray())
```

The second parameter of the ToTable method is a ParamArray with the names of the columns you want to get from the source table. To get this value we could use a bit of Linq over the destination table to extract the column names

Comment: Thanks Steve Works Great